# Master-Slave replication with additional selective replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Using MySQL 5.6 Enterprise is it possible to have a normal master/slave replication between a master and slave with full replication then a second slave server to only have certain tables?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the binary log that is used for replication always contains all statements for given databases. By default `binlog-do-db` configuration option on master tells that all databases should be replicated.

On slave side, there is option to only apply binlog statements for certain tables.

Specifying

```
replicate-do-table=database.table
```

will only do replication on that specific table.

In your case, you should use the default `binlog-do-db` statement to log all databases to binary log. On the second slave, you should apply the option above for all tables you want to replicate.